# bash function that outputs all input parameters including quotes or backslashes

Tags: bash, function, parameters, escaping

In bash on OS X, I can make a function like this:

```
function bla() { echo "$@"; }
```

Now when I do:

```
bla foo bar
```

the output is obvous: `foo bar`

When I do `bla "foo bar"` or `bla foo\ bar`, in both cases the output is still `foo bar`.
Not `"foo bar"` or `foo\ bar`.

I understand why, but is there a way to have a function output all arguments *exactly* as specified?

Comment: Try `bla '"foo bar"'` not sure if the backslashes are needed.

Comment: Quotes are consumed as the argument is read, they are not part of the argument.

Comment: @JonnyHenly They are not.

Comment: @JonnyHenly if I type `bla '"foo bar"'` I would want the output to be `'"foo bar"'`. I want to echo back *exactly* what I entered.

Comment: That isn't how the shell works.

Comment: @123 So `bla "foo bar"` and `bla foo\ bar` are essentialy the same, they both call the `bla` function with one single argument, a string `foo bar` ? Whereas `bla foo bar` calls the `bla` function with two arguments one string `foo` and one string `bar`. Right?

Comment: @RocketNuts Yes, they are both a single argument. And yes an unquoted unescaped space separates arguments.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you want this behaviour?

Comment: @123 OK, and is there a (distinguishable) difference between `bla foo bar` or `bla   foo   bar` (note the multiple spaced between arguments) - edit: oh, I can't put that properly in a comment. Well I meant `bla <several spaces> foo <several spaces> bar`.

Comment: No, unescaped spaces are compressed.

Comment: @TomFenech yes, for debugging purposes I want to prefix certain command lines in some scripts with `bla` so I can easily switch between actually executing them, or just echoing them, or both.

Comment: @RocketNuts You can use `trap DEBUG` and  `$BASH_COMMAND` to echo exactly what is typed.

Comment: @123 almost.  Shell aliases are processed when the command is read, and if the command contains an alias then $BASH_COMMAND exhibits the effects of its expansion.

Answer (score -2):

I have only tried this on Linux, but I guess it will be the same on OS X. You have to escape all special characters with a backslash. So your function will be the same but when you call it you have to escape the characters you  want echo'ed eg.

```
bla \"foo bar\"
```

or

```
bla foo\\ bar
```

Hope that helps.